# Android Firebase : null pointer exception in user registration

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

i am registering users to my app with this code,my app crashes on registration and gives a

```
"FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.ghost.prochat.MainActivity$1.onComplete(MainActivity.java:134)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc$1.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5069)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)"
```

My code has no syntax errors in that line, what can I do?

Here the method that register the user with Firebase:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.ALL, "createUserWithEmailAndPassword:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
            registerProgressDlg.dismiss();
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.ALL, "createUserWithEmailAndPassword", task.getException());
                Utils.showDialog(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        getString(R.string.err_singup));
            }
            else {
                final ArrayList<String> defaultRoom = new ArrayList<String>();
                defaultRoom.add("home");
                // Update the user profile information
                final FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                        .setDisplayName(String.valueOf(displayUsername))
                        .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"))
                        .build();
                user.updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.ALL, "User profile updated.");
                            // Construct the ChatUser
                            UserList.user = new ChatUser(user.getUid(),displayUsername, editTextEmail,true,defaultRoom);
                            // Setup link to users database
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(user.getUid()).setValue(UserList.user);
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserList.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What line are you getting your NullPointerException? I.e. which line is 134 in the code you pasted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: please share some more code of error log and your activity code.I think you haven't initialized instance of FirebaseAuth .

Comment: Post the line 134 of your Activity. The log is clear, the error is there

Comment: @barq registerProgressDlg.dismiss(); is my line 134

Comment: Based on your comment, the `registerProgressDIg` is  not initialized.

Comment: post complete stack trace of your crash.

Comment: @MikeKeepsOnShine said your `registerProgressDlg.dismiss()` please comment this line and run again.

Comment: @SirGeorge Please show your code for your declaration/initialization of registerProgressDlg.

Comment: i initialised the registerProgressDlg, but now i get  Process: com.example.ghost.prochat, PID: 4453
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ProgressDialog.dismiss()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.example.ghost.prochat.MainActivity$1.onComplete(MainActivity.java:137)

Comment: @MikeKeepsOnShine  when i comment the line registerProgressDlg.dismiss() i get an Error message by the app" Error occured while signing up"

Comment: @SirGeorge i never said to comment the line. I said that the error is in that line and to check the initialization, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, the `registerProgressDIg` is  the problem.

It is not initialized, try to do this, meanwhile:

```
if(registerProgressDIg!= null && registerProgressDIg.isShowing()){
       registerProgressDIg.dismiss();
}
```

BTW, check where you instantiate and initialize the `registerProgressDIg`

Comment: now the app doesnt crash but i am getting an error "Error registering user"

Comment: That error is given by Firebase, so it is another scenario :)

Comment: can you look at this  serviceID=16, operation=ValidateAuthServiceOperation
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: onPostInitComplete can be called only once per call to getRemoteService
                                                     at kqa.a(:com.google.android.gms:74)
                                                     at kna.a(:com.google.android.gms:987)
                                                     at knw.a(:com.google.android.gms:66)

Comment: That should be caused beacuse you nested two calls. Try to create a separate method that does the 'user.updateProfile' operations.
e.g: you add a listener on irebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword, get the result and AFTER THAT, based on the result, you call (or not) user.updateProfile

Answer (score 0):

As @MikeKeepsOnShine i think your `ProgressDialog` is Null. You have not initialized and try to dismiss() in you `onComplete()` method. First you have to initialized and that after dismiss. Please try this.

```
ProgressDialog registerProgressDIg = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this)
registerProgressDIg.show()

FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {


            if(registerProgressDIg!= null && registerProgressDIg.isShowing()){
                registerProgressDIg.dismiss();   
            }

            //paste your code as it.

    });
}
```